# Import CSV postgresql with pgAdmin 4

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I tried to import a csv file in a table with this code:

```
COPY sample("Telephone")
FROM 'C:\sample1.csv';
```

but returned me this:

Not connected to the server or the connection to the server has been closed.

What is the problem? I tried to change in the postgresql.conf file the parameters #log_connections and #log_disconnections from off to on but without results.

Comment: Does it work with `psql`?

Comment: I'm new in postgreql and know only this method to import csv file

Comment: No idea for this problem?